# Multiple data stored into a field for better management?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling, one-to-many

I have a MySQL table as follow:

```
id, user, culprit, reason, status, ts_register, ts_update
```

I was thinking of using the reason as an int field and store just the id of the reason that could be selected by the user and the reason itself could be increased by the admin.

What I meant by increased is that the admin could register new reason, for example currently we have:

```
Flood, Racism, Hacks, Other
```

But the admin could add a new reason for instance:

```
Refund
```

Now my problem is that I would like to allow my users to select multiple reasons, for example:

**The report 01 have the reasons Flood and Hack.**

How should I store the reason field so that I could select multiple reasons while maintaining a good table format?

Should I just go ahead and store it as a string and cast it as an INT when I am searching thru it or there are better forms to store it?

**UPDATE Based on Jonathan's reply:**

```
SELECT mt.*, group_concat(r.reason separator ', ') AS reason
  FROM MainTable AS mt
  JOIN MainReason AS mr ON mt.id = mr.maintable_ID
  JOIN Reasons AS r ON mr.reason = r.reason_id
  GROUP BY mt.id
```

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is available in MySQL; I know it can be simulated in some other DBMS (Informix, PostgreSQL), and and I don't know about other DBMS.  It is a useful aggregate.

Comment: @Jonathan thanks for the answer I was kinda worry that using the group_concat to my needs wanst the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normalized solution is to have a second table containing one row for each reason:

```
CREATE TABLE MainReasons
(
    MainTable_ID INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES MainTable(ID),
    Reason       INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Reasons(ID),
    PRIMARY KEY(MainTable_ID, Reason)
);
```

(Assuming your main table is called MainTable and you have a table defining valid reason codes called Reasons.)

---

From a comment:

> [W]ould you be [so] kind [as] to show me an example of selecting something to retrieve a report's reason? I mean if I simple select it SELECT * FROM MainTABLE I would never get any reasons since MainTable doesnt know it right? Because it is only linked to the MainReasons and Reasons table so I would need to do something like SELECT * FROM MainTable LEFT JOIN MainReasons USING (MainTable_ID) or something alike but how would I go about getting all the reasons if multiples?

```
SELECT mt.*, r.reason
  FROM MainTable AS mt
  JOIN MainReason AS mr ON mt.id = mr.maintable_ID
  JOIN Reasons AS r ON mr.reason = r.reason_id
```

This will return one row per reason - so it would return multiple rows for a single report (recorded in what I called MainTable).  I omitted the reason ID number from the results - you can include it if you wish.

You can add criteria to the query, adding terms to a WHERE clause.  If you want to see the reports where a specific reason is specified:

```
SELECT mt.*
  FROM MainTable AS mt
  JOIN MainReason AS mr ON mt.id = mr.maintable_ID
  JOIN Reasons AS r ON mr.reason = r.reason_id
 WHERE r.reason = 'Flood'
```

(You don't need the reason in the results - you know what it is.)

---

If you want to see the reports where 'Floods' and 'Hacks' were the reasons given, then you can write:

```
SELECT mt.*
  FROM MainTable AS mt
  JOIN (SELECT f.MainTable_ID
          FROM (SELECT MainTable_ID
                  FROM MainReason AS mr1
                  JOIN Reasons    AS r1  ON mr1.reason = r1.reason_ID
                 WHERE r1.reason = 'Floods'
               ) AS f ON f.MainTable_ID = mt.MainTable_ID
  JOIN (SELECT f.MainTable_ID
          FROM (SELECT MainTable_ID
                  FROM MainReason AS mr2
                  JOIN Reasons    AS r2  ON mr2.reason = r2.reason_ID
                 WHERE r1.reason = 'Hacks'
               ) AS h ON h.MainTable_ID = mt.MainTable_ID
```

Comment: So basicly I would have a 3rd table to link the reasons to their report, and how would a select work in this case just wondering, would I left join to gather the reasons name ?

Comment: @Prix: yes, three tables (MainTable, Reasons, MainReasons - a M:N relation table, sometimes called a linking table, between MainTable and Reasons).  No need for left join - usually.  But yes, joins.  Databases are good a joins, especially when one table is tiny (like the Reasons table would be).

Comment: I am possible asking for too much but would you be kind to show me an example of selecting something to retrive a report's reason ? I mean if I simple select it `SELECT * FROM MainTABLE` I would never get any reasons since MainTable doesnt know it right ? Because it is only linked to the MainReasons and Reasons table so I would need to do something like `SELECT * FROM MainTable LEFT JOIN MainReasons USING (MainTable_ID)` or something alike but how would I go about getting all the reasons if multiples ? not sure if I said it right.

Comment: that helps a lot but I am still stucked, I have my php pulling the data but like you said if a report have multiple reasons it comes in a new row(so basicly it will repeat the entry) while I would like to pull each entry with all reasons just once. Is there a query that would allow me to grab all the report reason without having to open a second query inside the loop to get the reason or the best way is to have a second query inside to check it?

Comment: I have came up with a query that might work for my needs but I am not entirely sure it would be an acceptable query would you mind checking it out ? It is on the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 1):

To do a one-to-many relationship, I would spin reason off into it's own table, like so:

```
id, parent_id, reason
```

parent_id would refer back into your current table's id.

You could store it as an INT, but it would be a continual pain to have to parse it every time you wanted to read the data.  This way would just take one more join.

Comment: What benefit accrues from the 'id' column?

Comment: @dpmattingly I dont think I understood your idea would you mind explaining it a bit more ? You can combine all reasons so you are suggesting that I have 3rd table where it would register all the reasons to a report ? It seems more overcomplicated if I understood you correctly

Comment: By habit, I put a separate primary key field in all my tables.  Technically, you could probably do without, since (parent_id, reason) should be unique.

Comment: As in my table where I declare the primary key to be the composite of two columns - parent_id and reason in your notation.

Comment: @Prix The ivory-tower reason is that it leads to a normalized database, which I have been told is a Good Thing.  The pragmatic reason is that I don't want to have to resort to string manipulation every time I want to add or remove a reason.

Comment: @Le Dorfier: there can be many rows in the linking table for a given ID in the main table; each row in the linking table is distinct by virtue of having the same ID but a different reason code.

Comment: Yes, linking tables is how one does many-to-many. This answer describes (quote) one-to-many (and as best I can figure out what "it" and "id" are referring to) that's what they are describing. Your answer OTOH is correct, esp. after adding the explanation. Nice job.